# C# access files from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, silverlight-4.0

I am having a solution consisting on silverlight and web project. i want to access a file which is located inside a folder in web project from my silverlight project.how can this be done.

this file is a users manual document for which i have to provide the download functionality to the user..

Comment: what you have looked for so far?

Comment: Just go to the solution explorer, right click on the Silverlight project, select "add existing item" , navigate to the folder with file and it, but on the button select "as reference".

Comment: you can use HttpRequst and HttpResponse class to access the file from another web-application.

Comment: Please clarify, what would you like to do - access file so it is a shared code, or access the class represented by the file?

Comment: this file is a users manual document(which resides in another web project in my solution) for which i have to provide the download functionality to the user from my silverlight project

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Silverlight project and select Add --> Existing item. 
In the dialog, navigate to the location of the web project. Select the file(s) you need but instead of clicking on "Add", click on the dropdown next to the Add button and select "Add As Link".

Comment: after this how can i access the file programmatically

Comment: If this is not a code file, you probably want to use the save file dialog along with Webclient to stream the file similar to how it's done here :http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx

Comment: i do not want the user to select the file to download with save file dialog.

Comment: So, do you want it to be downloaded automatically? Or provide a link as you would on a web site? In both cases some kind of dialog/notification will appear, depending on the user's browser settings.

Comment: @Rohan: The user doesn't need to select a file.If you refer to the link I included, the user would need to click on a button(download manual in your case). In the click handler you would then need to stream the file to the user

Answer (score 0):

In your Silverlight project:

1. Right-click References > Add Reference.
2. On the left tab, select Solution.
3. Select which project(s) you want to include a reference to.

In Silverlight project C# files, you may have to add a 'using' statement if you are trying to use a Class from a referenced project.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solutions as below,

```
var uri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../DirectoryName/FileName.docx"); 
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri);
```